# How to refresh the Palette

Tags: java, netbeans, lookup, netbeans-platform, palette

i have follow [THIS GUIDE](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi3.html) for create a Palette in my Netbeans Platform application (*Using Explorer Views to View Data*).

Now, the Palette is shown but i want refresh it with new elements.

I have tryed to re-associate the `Lookup`, change the `RootNode` and create a new `PaletteController`, but nothing.

How can i do? There is a method for do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the list of categories and items in a Netbeans Platform palette by using `PaletteController.refresh()`, as noted [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-palette/org/netbeans/spi/palette/PaletteController.html#refresh()).